# UTF-8 char encoding does not work on console (Linux)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, encoding, utf-8

In my java program I want to output this character: ⊨

It works in Eclipse but doesn't on my bash console.

Here's my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
    System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().name());
    String original = "\u22A8";
    System.out.println("original = " + original);
}
```

Here's my output in Eclipse built-in console. Note that I set `Run Configurations > Common > Encoding > Other > UTF-8`

```
UTF-8
UTF-8
original = ⊨
```

Here's my output on terminal when invoking with `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Main`

```
UTF-8
UTF-8
original = â¨
```

Here's my output on terminal when invoking with `java Main`

```
ANSI_X3.4-1968
US-ASCII
original = ?
```

How can I make it work on console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to set the encoding inside the console. So when setting it to UTF-8, the invocation `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Main` yields the correct result.

Comment: How exactly do you set the encoding inside the console?  Window / Preferences / Run-Debug / Console does not have such option