# Jenkins: console output characters

Tags: jenkins, console, debian

Does anyone know how to beat such chars in Jenkins console output log?

Seems there is a problem with UTF-8.

[image: Console output]

Answer (score 17):

The issue here is that the characters are not being output as UTF-8 to your console.  I think the solution is to tell `jenkins` when you invoke it to write output as UTF-8.  See this solution for a similar problem [UTF-8 char encoding does not work on console (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619592/utf-8-char-encoding-does-not-work-on-console-linux)

Something like
`java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 jenkins.war` might do the trick

Comment: Did you ever figure out where you run this command from?

Answer (score 9):

In Jenkins ver. 2.46.2, I just got this to work by going to Nodes, Advanced settings, JVM Options and putting `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` and then taking that node offline and online again. Hope this helps other people. It would be great if UTF8 support was default.

Comment: that works only for slave node. maser node does not seem to have such an option

Answer (score 3):

To give the the answer more complete. 
If you use an tomcat container to run jenkins, then edit `catalina.sh` config file:

```
vim apache-tomcat-path/bin/catalina.sh
```

Add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the **JAVA_OPTS** var and restart tomcat will do the trick. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works great. I tried other answers but none worked.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using a build-agent and a pipeline, add this to the agent's dockerfile, and no further jenkins settings are needed

```
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried everything with file.encoding variable, but didn't work.

My solution was to check environment locale variables in Jenkins Controller and Agent node where job is actually runing, and make them match.

In my case, agent node running the job required environment variable `"LC_ALL=C.UTF-8"`, which was already defined in controller node.

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68217405/3284482

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the encoding with you are opening your file to 'utf-8' and check your encoding saved for the script in vs code(whatever platform)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUg7s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using AnsiColor plugin in Jenkins. This worked for me. I had tried all the above solutions but nothing happened. As I downloaded AnsiColor plugin everything got fixed!