# How set encodings in Jenkins to UTF-8

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, utf-8

Cyrillic symbols in the Console output are not displayed correctly.
Jenkins is running through Tomcat / 8.5.11 on Windows 7 
The Jenkins property displays: 
file.encoding Cp1251
sun.jnu.encoding Cp1251
sun.stderr.encoding cp866
sun.stdout.encoding cp866

**How can I set the encoding on UTF-8 in Jenkins?** Encoding in autotest code is UTF-8. 
It is example problem in Cyrillic text
_РјР°РєСЃРёРјСѓРј_РёРЅС„РѕСЂРјР°С†РёРё

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803733/default-character-encoding-for-java-console-output try this

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), as you've apparently already done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created file setenv.bat in bin folder and set JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

---

Note that the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable may already be set with useful data (like `JAVA_OPTS='-Djava.util.logging.config.file=<..>`), so first check its current value and then append the extra  `-Dfile.encoding` setting at the end of the existing string value.

Answer (score 9):

According to this answer:
[JVM property -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 or UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031877/jvm-property-dfile-encoding-utf8-or-utf-8)

You have to add this JVM setting to your Jenkins starting script (JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS):

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Comment: Note that you need to do this both on the master node and on all slave nodes as well.

Answer (score 1):

For agents with this Console Output:

[image: BEFORE]

Make sure agent's environment variable `"LC_ALL=C.UTF-8"` is set; Consle Output would return afterwards:

[image: AFTER]

Sample Pipeline:

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            
            echo 'Hello World'          
            
            // Latin characters always OK here.
            echo 'áéíóú' 
            
            script {
               
               // Agent requires env variable `"LC_ALL=C.UTF-8"`
               // to see 'ó' correctly through Console Output.
               sh "echo Versión ..."
               
               // Check available locales
               sh "locale -a"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Using Jenkins within Docker:

Jenkins Controller - Version 2.289.2; image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11

Jenkins Agent - Repo Digest ID: jenkins/ssh-agent@sha256:3292bc96

Comment: Worth mentioning that the node needs to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your Jenkins installation directory and open the Jenkins XML file.
2. Add the highlighted text(-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ffm5ZlpBy3SGcvc6J21P62HDH36vByzI/view and save.
3. Open Command Prompt -->Go to your Jenkins installation directory and enter the command to stop Jenkins :- jenkins.exe stop
4. Restart jenkins by entering the command at the command prompt:- jenkins.exe restart
5. Re-run build in jenkins and check the console output. https://prnt.sc/zoi3BmOAcKQ5