# Adding JVM setting to Jenkins starting script

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I installed Jenkins on AWS EC2 Linux server but it doesn't support the UTF8 encoding. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46112346/6470918) I can fix that by adding `JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS`
to the Jenkins starting script, but I cannot find where the script is and how to modify it. If it matters, I started the Jenkins by running `sudo service jenkins start`