# Jenkins Console Output is displaying in binary or in Special Character Format

Tags: jenkins

I have created a localhost Freestyle Jenkins jobs which contain Postman COllection JSON File. on Running the Jenkins Build, Console Output is displaying in Special Characters which is the non-readable format. [image] I am using Jenkins **v2.126** PFB The Snippet of Console Output

```
"[90mâ”Œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€[39m[90mâ”¬â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€[39m[90mâ”¬â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”�[39m
[90mâ”‚[39m                         [90mâ”‚[39m executed [90mâ”‚[39m   failed [90mâ”‚[39m
[90mâ”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€[39m[90mâ”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€[39m[90mâ”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤[39m
[90mâ”‚[39m              [32miterations[39m [90mâ”‚[39m        1 [90mâ”‚[39m        0 [90mâ”‚[39m
[90mâ”œâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â"
```

Is this need some separate Plugin to Install?

Comment: In most my cases I've got this fixed by adding -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  on jenkins start - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960996/jenkins-console-output-characters

Answer (score 2):

please try this when you run jenkins war file "java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar jenkins.war". i hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `--no-color` flag in your command, if you can use `--no-color` flag in your command , then add it, it will fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the encoding to 'UTF-8', which you should do, you can also install the AnsiColor plugin to ensure colors are rendered in the browser appropriately.  That will be better in the long term than disabling colors in every tool you use.