# Jenkins Console Print Encoded Characters

Tags: docker, jenkins, utf-8, character-encoding, jenkins-pipeline

When outputting characters from a declarative pipeline running inside a linux container is it possible to change the encoding to match the true output from the terminal? I.e.

```
├── file1                         +-- file1
├── file2                         +-- file2
└── file3                         +-- file3

^Formatting I want                ^Formatting I get
```

.

I tried passing the following arguments to my Docker Agent:

```
-e JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" 

-e LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

.

Combined with:

```
sh returnStdout: true, script: " "
```

And got â”œâ”€â”€ in place of the "+--", which seems to be the ANSI encoding for the "├──".

I am using the ansiColor Option but that didn't seem to help much.

.

I saw this similar question, but I was unsure on how to implement the solution in the pipeline.

[Jenkins: console output characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960996/jenkins-console-output-characters)

Comment: Try https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-resolve-utf-8-encoding-issue-jenkins-ajuram-salim/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Jenkins II to change the encoding to UTF-8. 
Go to 
**Jenkins** -> **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** -> **Global properties**

and add two envirenment variables `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and `LANG` having values `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and `en_US.UTF-8` respectively

. [image]

After adding these you may need to restart Jenkins.

**Reference**: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-resolve-utf-8-encoding-issue-jenkins-ajuram-salim/

**UPDATE:**

or you can update `<arguments>` in `jenkins.xml` file.
e.g.

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this and it didn't work. I was able fix my issue by deleting my local jenkins and running java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar jenkins.war, but that option isn't feasible for our production jenkins. Do you know of a jenkins startup folder that runs java commands?

Comment: OOH, you totally led my to the answer that worked for me. I added "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to the jenkins config file (jenkins.xml) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here is the official answer from cloudbees. Unfortunately all of these did not work for me.

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004397911-How-to-address-issues-with-unmappable-characters-

Add these to JVM Arguments in master and also on agents -

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: only this helped in my case.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me as well. To clarify, the changes needed to be made in the Jenkins.xml file on the master, and the jenkins-slave.xml file on the agents and in the arguments section for both.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was really in specifying the optional 'encoding' parameter to the 'sh' pipeline step: [sh: Shell Script](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script)

Of course, this will only work provided the file.encoding is set properly as described in other posts here.

Comment: I tried every possible environment variable, flags, agent configurations. 
And this is the fist solution that made it work for me. Agent running on a MacOS 

Thanks!